# Neo4j Potential Memory Leak

Tags: memory, neo4j, out-of-memory, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

We are using apoc plugin to delete nodes from neo4j db but observing high memory usage. We see that temporary memory deletes but not happening in our case. We are using community edition, so we are not able to diagnose much.

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/3696) for this.

```
"CALL
apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (cl:Node1 {id: '" + label1 + "'}) -[:BELONGS]-> (c) return c","DETACH DELETE c",
{ batchSize: " + deleteBatchSize + ", parallel: " + deleteParallelCheck + ", concurrency: " + deleteConcurrencySize + ", retries: " + deleteRetriesAttempts + " })"
```

Below are parameters for same:

```
delete.parallel.check=true
delete.batch.size=2000
delete.concurrency.size=20
delete.retries.attempts=3
```

Comment: Please fix this sentence: "We see that temporary memory deletes but not happening in our case."

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case, as soon as a batch starts working, its transaction blocks all other batches until it completes. So it makes no sense to do your query in parallel, as it uses up a lot of resources without gaining you anything.

##### Explanation

Whenever a transaction deletes a relationship, a write lock is placed on the relationship and its end nodes (because they all have to be modified in some way). That blocks other transactions from updating the same entities.

In your use case, `DETACH DELETE c` deletes a `c` node and its `BELONGS` relationship. But *all* the `BELONGS` relationships to be deleted are connected to *the same* `cl` node (assuming `Node1` nodes have unique `id` values).

So, as soon as a batch (transaction) starts deleting relationships, it imposes a write lock on the single shared `cl`, and all other batches have to wait (and take up memory) until that first batch completes and releases the write lock on `cl`. And then the scenario repeats.

Not all use cases are amenable to parallelization.

##### Conclusion

Do not execute your query in parallel. Just do something like this (where `$id1` is passed as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)) directly:

```
MATCH (:Node1 {id: $id1})-[:BELONGS]->(c)
DETACH DELETE c
```

[UPDATE]

If there are have many `c` nodes to delete, you can run out of memory with the above query, since everything is done in a single transaction.

To avoid that, you can perform the deletion in batches using [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/) (with an appropriate batch size, depending on your situation):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (:Node1 {id: $id1})-[:BELONGS]->(c)",
  "DETACH DELETE c",
  {batchSize: 5000})
```

Note that we leave the procedure's [`parallel` config parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/#_config_parameters) defaulted to `false`, to avoid the write-lock blocking issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply however MATCH (:Node1 {id: $id1})-[:BELONGS]->(c)
DETACH DELETE c is giving us out of memory as data we have to delete is huge...Example 5 Million records in fraction of seconds...Can you suggest something else?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you are using the Browser, it should help.